# Haskell regex-pcre negate expression

Tags: regex, haskell, pcre

How can I achieve an inverse match so that for example

```
 getAllTextMatches $ "foobar  bar    bl   a" =~ pattern :: [String]
```

would prodcuce a list of strings that are not multiple whitespace.

I've tried

```
getAllTextMatches $ "foobar  bar    bl   a" =~ "(\\s\\s+)" :: [String]
```

which returns me this list as expected: `["  ","    ","   "]`

Now I tried to negate the expression the following way

```
getAllTextMatches $ "foobar  bar    bl   a" =~ "(?!\\s\\s+)" :: [String]
```

which returned  `[""]`
whereas I wanted to receive this:

```
["foobar", "bar", "bl", "a"]
```

Or as another example whereas

```
getAllTextMatches $ "foobar /* bla */ bar bl a" =~ "/\\*[^*]*\\*/" :: [String]
```

returns `["/* bla */"]`

I woud like to receive: `["foobar "," bar bl a"]` by negating `"/\\*[^*]*\\*/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a split:

split your string with your original pattern and you will obtain what you want.

OR

you can try to match with:

```
(?>\\s\\s+\\K|^)(?>\\S|\\s(?!\\s+))++
```

and

```
(?>/\\*[^*]*\\*/\\K|^)(?>[^/]++|/(?!\\*[^*]*\\*/))++
```

where `\K` is a pcre feature that resets the begining of the match.

Comment: @DominikDanter: You are right these patterns don't work, I remove them.